Geyser messages are being sent earlier to my local computer in compare with my server even though my server in the same place
I'm running rust code while when I'm running the .exe file from my local computer I get the yellowstone geyser messages like 1-4 seconds faster than the geyser messages that are being sent to my server that is running the exact same code in Frankfurt (the gRPC node is Amsterdam - 7ms).
I can't understand the reason for it, my local computer is like 80ms from the node and the server is 7ms so the server geyser messages should be faster as I see it.
My OS is "Windows 10" while the server is "Windows Server 2019" I also tried to execute it through ubuntu server and had the same results as the windows server one.
The specs are almost the same and I checked at the server, while the code is running the CPU, Memory is at around 1% so it's not overload.
Can u think of any reason for it ?
Will appreciate any clue!

Have you tried reaching out to the yellowstone team? They might give some better information

@JonC I'm waiting for their but I'm pretty sure it's the hardware, because I checked the performance of the hardware in the server and it was pretty bad in compare with my desktop.
Also I checked with my laptop which is pretty weak in compare with my desktop and it also had delay as the servers so it's not the network but can only be hardware issue as far as I see it.

Ah ok, that might be the issue, sorry I couldn't give more concrete help!
